# What the interest of copying the reference of a field in a method body to read it while the field is never reassigned?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I was looking at the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` code in .NET Core and I've notice a kind of coding pattern also used in some builtin datastructures like `Queue<T>` or `Stack<T>` and `List<T>`.

For example about the : 
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs#L482

We have:

```
Entry[] entries = _entries;
IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = _comparer;
```

I am not really sure why we keep a variable of the reference of the comparer and the entries, to me it's still referencing the same field.

It's not like the field is reassigned at some point if the same method body.

What is the interest of copying the reference if it's not reassigned, if there is some optimizations done by the compiler which would avoid `this.field` traversal?

Comment: My guess is that it is to make other developers lives easier. If someone reads the latter half of the code and sees a `_comparer` and he wants to know what type it is, he won't need to scroll up very far.

Comment: @Sweeper well some other fields are not leveraging that technique (e.g. `_version`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it is *probably* a hand-optimization, either for speed, or for smaller code size, or both.

Dereferencing a local variable is cheaper in terms of clock cycles than dereferencing a member variable, (which means that the C# compiler and JITter are not nearly as smart as I had hoped them to be,) and it is also more compact in terms of IL code length.

A local variable can usually be accessed with one IL instruction, and after JITting it can also usually be accessed with just one machine code instruction.

A member variable needs more work.  At the IL level, we must specify that we want to access the `this` pointer, and that we want to access something at an offset from it, and we must specify the field identifying the member variable.  After JITting, it depends how smart the JITter is, in theory it could be done in one instruction if the JITter can guarantee that a certain register always contains the address of `this`, but such a guarantee is hard to be had, so what is probably happening is that it takes one instruction to load `this` into a register and one more instruction to access the field at an offset from that register.

It is never worth coding like that when writing application code.  But when writing a library that is used by huge numbers of people all over the planet around the clock, it makes sense to write the code so as to squeeze clock cycles here and there.

Comment: Hi, care to add a reference to `MSDN` or something else? (maybe generated IL code of the two examples given)

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete you are right, the answer is not complete without such an example, but it is ten minutes to 2 o'clock in the morning here, and I need to go to sleep.

Comment: @Mike Nakis that makes sense, thanks for your answer. I am going to investigate a bit more in that direction, any idea why would the `_version` is not using that particular technique?

Comment: Maybe not the best example, but the IL difference between A and B does show using the local to produce less IL: [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQDk4BstWFiAJQkiQDsBjCAFQE8AHFAGhhAEssAfAAQAYACbgEYA3AFgAUNwDMggEz8AwvwDek/hv70EbAG6wIgoQID6MFDH4BefgGUYOsgHMAdAFEAtvRi1xEzfzqmjJGAgCCABQAlKpBARrCAubIljZmFn7xmmxgEcmpNgBEAGIA9qWFUXFZwQDs/CXlhZk1OXkW1kUAQlAIldU1gvWFPX0tWdz1+eP8AL7V1SGJ/F3Rsf6tuekpnQ1lFVUbgwnD+80D2Vv5uyO9/UfHkw2j5w8BT9swM/MSs0A)

Comment: @JonathonChase true seems the local is helping in that regard, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @JonathonChase yeah, I see the 3 calls to `this` when using the field vs once using the local `string`